# SEO: não aparece a descrição do site no google

Tags: seo

Quando procuro meu site no google aparece a mensagem:

> Não há nenhuma informação disponível para esta página.

Para aparecer a descrição, já coloquei a *tag* `meta description` no *header* e meu `robots.txt` está dessa forma:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Precisa fazer mais alguma coisa? Eu sei que leva um tempo pro *google* varrer o *site* para pegar as novas informações, mas já faz um bom tempo que está assim.

Comment: Por quê tem o `Disallow: /`? *The "User-agent: *" means this section applies to all robots. The "Disallow: /" **tells the robot that it should not visit any pages** on the site.*, [documentação](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

Comment: Esse arquivo já estava criado antes de eu começar a trabalhar nesse site. Eu achava que a "/" iria bloquear tudo de ser anexado, mas o site está sendo exibido normal nas buscas, o único problema é a descrição. Tu acha que se eu remover a "/", vai ler normalmente o meta description?

Comment: Cara pra começar tida essa barra com certeza. Mas lembre-se de bloquear Bots Russos, Chineses etc, se não te interessa que esses bots scanneiem seu site. Outra coisa, se vc trocou o Discription a pouco tempo é normal que o Google demore até uma semana para atualizar esse texto

Comment: @hugocsl Ok, vou fazer isso. Só uma coisa, mesmo com a barra, o google tá indexando o site, não deveria estar acontecendo isso né? Já que a barra está bloqueando todo site.

Comment: Na verdade se vc procurar vc vai ver que o Robots não é uma garantia de não indexalção, principalmente se vc usa outras serviços como Google Analytics na sua página...